# Creating a custom module in YUI3 using module pattern

Tags: javascript, module, namespaces, yui, yui3

In my module, I would like to make some variables and functions expose to the public, but I am not sure which way it should be written.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    YUI.add('my-module1', function (Y) {

              Y.namespace("MyModule1");

              var privateVar='some data';
              var privateFunc=function(){...};

              /*should I do it like this?*/
              Y.MyModule1.publicVar='some data';
              Y.MyModule1.publicFunc=function(){...};


              /*or is this correct if I do it like this?*/
              var publicVar='some data';
              var publicFunc=function(){...};

              return{
                  publicVar: publicVar,
                  publicFunc: publicFunc
              };


    }, '0.0.1', {
              requires: []
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do it the first way, by attaching public members to the Y, not by returning an object.

See http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/yui/#yuiadd and https://github.com/yahoo/yui3-cookbook/blob/master/examples/loading/add_basic.html for examples.